# recursive Function returning promise

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise, es6-promise

I'm working on an Ionic 3 Project, that's mean I'm using Angular 5, ES6, TypeScript.

I'm trying to write a recursive function that returns a promise but I've get an execution error:

In fact, I'm trying to do a function which wait until the condition is verified or until timeout of 5s, some thing like that
wait until (myCondition | timeout) then return a resolved or rejected promise.

The function tests every 100ms, if condition verified it return a resolved promise, else it make a recursive appel until the 50th call so it returns a rejected promise:

## code:

```
  waitForTrack(flag,callNumber){
    if(callNumber < 50){
      if (this._audioProvider.tracks.length == flag)
        setTimeout(()=>{ 
          return this.waitForTrack(flag,callNumber++)},100)
      else
        return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{ 
          resolve();
        });
    }else{
      return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{ 
        reject();
      });
    }
  }
```

## Error:

```
core.js:1449 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

Comment: `waitForTrack` isn't guaranteed to return anything at the moment. `return` inside a `setTimeout` won't affect code outside

Comment: in your `setTimeout` your return won't return anything

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that setTimeout never return any result from its body, So the solution will be using Promise because reject() or resolve() could be executed in the body of a setTimeout:

```
  waitForTrack(flag,callNumber){
        return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{ 
          if (this._audioProvider.tracks.length == flag){
            resolve();
          }else if (callNumber > 49)
              reject();
            else
              setTimeout(()=>this.waitForTrack(flag,callNumber++),100);
        });
  }
```